# How I get my divs to fade out in the reverse order the showed on load

Tags: jquery

I have 3 divs fading in on page load with delays. how do I fade them out in the reverse order they came in when I press a button? I also need the animations to finish playing before the page redirects

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      $("div#helloitsdan").fadeIn(700).delay(2000);
      $("div#line").delay(700).fadeIn(700);
      $("div#enter_site").delay(1000).fadeIn(700);
    });

$("a#click").click(function() {
          $("div#enter_site").fadeOut(80).delay(100);
          $("div#line").delay(50).fadeOut(80);
          $("div#helloitsdan").delay(70).fadeOut(80);
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should keep all your code (which is not needed globally) inside your init function, this will ensure that your `click` event is hooked when the DOM is ready. Then, all animation function do have an `onFinish` function callback, so use it, like so :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  $("div#helloitsdan").fadeIn(700).delay(2000);
  $("div#line").delay(700).fadeIn(700);
  $("div#enter_site").delay(1000).fadeIn(700);

  $("a#click").click(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');

    $("div#enter_site").fadeOut(80);
    $("div#line").delay(50).fadeOut(80);
    $("div#helloitsdan").delay(70).fadeOut(80, function() {
       window.location.href = href;  // redirect now
    });

    return false;  // do not redirect from the click now
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the `div`'s in through an array, then iterate through it backwards.  Also, when is your redirect coming?

Comment: Hi tim, thanks for the reply. the redirect comes when the button has been clicked

Answer (score 0):

`fadeOut()` should work better for fade them out effect in the click button event.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the callback function of the fadeOut() method.

```
$('div').fadeOut(80, function() {
    $('div2').fadeOut(80, function() {
        $('div3').fadeOut(80);
    });
});
```

The syntax may not be exactly right, but it's something like that.

More examples on using fadeout: http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/